# ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress with php 7 and oci8

Tags: oracle, initialization, php-7, shutdown, oci8

I had install server with php7 along with oci8 oracle php connection extension so when i am trying to connect with code

$conn = oci_connect("someuid", "somepass", "123.456.789/some.oraclecloud.internal");

then it says

"ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress"

I am not getting why this, when i talked to my technical team about oracle perspective then they said that every thing is ok at oracle server

please do resolve my problem

Comment: Either your tech team is wrong, or you are not connecting to the database they are talking about.  Check your connect string.

Comment: Did you specifiy the protocol (TCP)and the  listener port too,
your technical team my be wrong as this error generally occur in the server side

Comment: where do specify the protocol (TCP)and the listener port, Actually i am new about doing connect php with oracle

Comment: Ask your tech team.  Also check the connection section of PHP OCI8 doc or the 'Underground PHP and Oracle Manual'